# Elo Touch USB touchscreen not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, xorg, touchscreen

I have an ELO touch screen (ET700L) , which is connected through USB.

While the screen works out of the box with Ubuntu 18.04 , the touch functionality is not working.

When running **xinput list**, I can see my device listed:

```
Virtual core pointer
 - Virtual Core XTEST pointer
 - PixArt USB Optical mouse
 - EloTouchSystems, Inc Elo TouchSystems 2216 AccuTouch USB Touchmonitor Interface id=12 [slave pointer  (2)]
```

So the touchscreen seems to be detected properly, but still I have no touch functionality.

Xorg.0.log contains a number of entries regarding the touchscreen ( adding and removing it a number of times )

```
(II) event 13 - EloTouchSystems, Inc Elo TouchSystem 2216 Accutouch USB Touchmonitor Interface: device removed
```

However, Xorg.0.log ends with :

```
 (II) event 13 - EloTouchSystems, Inc Elo TouchSystem 2216 Accutouch USB Touchmonitor Interface: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
 (II) event 13 - EloTouchSystems, Inc Elo TouchSystem 2216 Accutouch USB Touchmonitor Interface: device is a touch device
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had some experience working with Elo touchscreens on an Ubuntu (Mate) 18.04 system.  Touch input wasn't working with the screen when I connected it, but after some testing, I found that if I remove/reinstall the hid_multitouch module it starts to work:

```
modprobe -r hid_multitouch; sleep 1; modprobe hid_multitouch
```

I have been looking to see if there's a better way to handle this, or if this should be considered a bug.  As a bug, I have no idea which system it would be filed with (kernel, Xorg, etc).  My expectation is that when the touchscreen is connected that the touch works without needing to perform any additional hacks, but for now that seems to work OK for me.